# Is there a way to get build and version number inside a project's class

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

I have a project created and maintained with algular-cli. I want to have an accessible value inside the project classes of a version number (from package.json maybe) and incremented build number (every time I do `ng build` or every time `ng serve` does it). How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that actual project version is in angular-cli.json, however I don't know how to access it from app

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve what I wanted. May be this would be interesting to someone.

I subclassed `MyAngular2App` from `Angular2App` in `angular-cli-build.js` and overriden method `read` of BroccoliPlugin. It is called each time the build happens. But there was another problem - if I updated `app/src/version.ts` broccoli-watcher triggered another round of build...
I tried different solutions, tried to exclude that file from watch etc with no success. So I solved this in more "system" way. Moved the file `version.ts` out of src folder and made symlink on its place. Symlink is not updated when the original file does.

`angular-cli-build.js`:

```
'use strict';

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');
var fs = require('fs');

class MyAngular2App extends Angular2App {
    constructor(project, inputNode, options) {
        super(project, inputNode, options);
    }

    read(x) {
        var _ver = require('./build_version.js');
        _ver.build++;
        _ver.version = _ver.x + '.' + _ver.y + '.' + _ver.z + '.' + _ver.build;
        console.log(" Build version: " + _ver.version);

        var fsErr = function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        };

        var ver = "exports.x = '" + _ver.x + "';\n" +
            "exports.y = '" + _ver.y + "';\n" +
            "exports.z = '" + _ver.z + "';\n" +
            "exports.build = " + _ver.build + ";\n";
        fs.writeFile("build_version.js", ver, fsErr);

        ver = "export const version = {\n    major: " + _ver.x + ",\n    minor: " + _ver.y + ",\n    patch: " + _ver.z + ",\n    build: "
            + _ver.build + ",\n    text: '" + _ver.version + "'\n};\n";
        fs.writeFile("version.ts", ver, fsErr);

        return super.read(x);
    }

}

module.exports = function (defaults) {
    return new MyAngular2App(defaults, {
        vendorNpmFiles: [
            'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
            'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
            'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
            'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
            '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
            'underscore/underscore-min.js',
            'stompjs/lib/stomp.min.js',
            'moment/moment.js'
        ]
    });
};
```

`build_version.js`

```
exports.x = '0';
exports.y = '7';
exports.z = '3';
exports.build = 2818;
```

`version.ts`:

```
export const version = {
    major: 0,
    minor: 7,
    patch: 3,
    build: 2818,
    text: '0.7.3.2818'
};
```